# Returning a new Dataframe (by transforming an existing one) using a function - spark/scala

Tags: html, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, data-cleaning

I am new to Spark. I am trying to read a `JSONArray` into a `Dataframe` and perform some transformations on it. I am trying to cleanse my data by removing some `html` tags and some `newline` characters. for example:

Initial dataframe read from JSON:

```
+-----+---+-----+-------------------------------+
|index|  X|label|      date                     |
+-----+---+-----+-------------------------------+
|    1|  1|    A|<div>&quot2017-01-01&quot</div>|
|    2|  3|    B|<div>2017-01-02</div>          |
|    3|  5|    A|<div>2017-01-03</div>          |
|    4|  7|    B|<div>2017-01-04</div>          |
+-----+---+-----+-------------------------------+
```

Should be transformed to :

```
+-----+---+-----+------------+
|index|  X|label|      date  |
+-----+---+-----+------------+
|    1|  1|    A|'2017-01-01'|
|    2|  3|    B|2017-01-02  |
|    3|  5|    A|2017-01-03  |
|    4|  7|    B|2017-01-04  |
+-----+---+-----+------------+
```

I know that we can perform these transformations using:

`df.withColumn("col_name",regexp_replace("col_name",pattern,replacement))`

I am able to cleanse my data using the `withColumn` as shown above. However, I have a large number of columns and writing a `.withColumn` method for every column doesn't seem to be elegant, concise or efficient. So I tried doing something like this:

```
  val finalDF = htmlCleanse(intialDF, columnsArray)

  def htmlCleanse(df: DataFrame, columns: Array[String]): DataFrame = {
    var retDF = hiveContext.emptyDataFrame
    for(i <- 0 to columns.size-1){
      val name = columns(i)
      retDF = df.withColumn(name,regexp_replace(col(name),"<(?:\"[^\"]*\"['\"]*|'[^']*'['\"]*|[^'\">])+>",""))
                .withColumn(name,regexp_replace(col(name),"&quot;","'"))
                .withColumn(name,regexp_replace(col(name),"&#160;"," "))
                .withColumn(name,regexp_replace(col(name),"&#58;",":"))
    }
    retDF
  }
```

I defined a new function `htmlCleanse` and I am passing the Dataframe to be transformed and the columns array to the function. The function creates a new `emptyDataFrame` and iterates over the columns list performing the cleansing on a column for a single iteration and assigns the transformed `df` to the `retDF` variable.

This gave me no errors, but it doesn't seem to remove the html tags from all the columns while some of the columns appear to be cleansed. Not sure what's the reason for this inconsistent behavior(any ideas on this?).

So, what would be an efficient way to cleanse my data? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first issue is that initializing for an empty frame does nothing, you just create something new. You can't then "add" things to it from another dataframe without a join (which would be a bad idea performance wise).

The second issue is that retDF is always defined from df. This means that you throw away everything you did except for cleaning the last column.

Instead you should initialize retDF to df and in every iteration fix a column and overwrite retDF as follows:

```
def htmlCleanse(df: DataFrame, columns: Array[String]): DataFrame = {
    var retDF = df 
    for(i <- 0 to columns.size-1){
      val name = columns(i)
      retDF = retDF.withColumn(name,regexp_replace(col(name),"<(?:\"[^\"]*\"['\"]*|'[^']*'['\"]*|[^'\">])+>",""))
                   .withColumn(name,regexp_replace(col(name),"&quot;","'"))
                   .withColumn(name,regexp_replace(col(name),"&#160;"," "))
                   .withColumn(name,regexp_replace(col(name),"&#58;",":"))
    }
    retDF
  }
```

Comment: any clue how to fix this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72963925/org-apache-spark-sql-analysisexception-unresolved-operator-project